# Custom page layout editable fields

Tags: page-layout

In my custom page layout there are no borders and captions next to my editable field. I want my editable fields to be displayed like below. Is it OOTB, how can i do that?

[image]

Comment: Please refer to this question with the solution here : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36989/how-to-format-richhtmlfield-in-publishing-site-custom-page-layout/37045#37045

Comment: I already saw that post but didnt succeed

Comment: what part of that process is making the border and caption actually? because the steps you provided is a standard custom page layout development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly what version of sharepoint is this in? Im going to take a guess that this is in 2010.

I think your talking about the chrome properties. In sharepoint 2007 it was easy - siteactions - edit page and select the webpart - edit and change its properties on the right.

For 2010 its slightly different:

[How to format RichHtmlField in Publishing site Custom Page Layout](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36989/how-to-format-richhtmlfield-in-publishing-site-custom-page-layout)

also

http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/10/27/custom-styles-for-sharepoint-2010-rich-html-field/

and

http://www.bentedder.com/customizing-markup-and-table-styles-in-sharepoint-richhtmlfield/#css

**EDIT**

You can do it through code:

```
SPFile file = web.GetFile("SitePages/home.aspx");

SPLimitedWebPartManager lwpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(

                System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);

SPLimitedWebPartCollection webpartColl = lwpm.WebParts;

foreach ( System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart wp in webpartColl)

{

                wp.ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.TitleAndBorder;

                lwpm.SaveChanges(wp);

}
```

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/9cb91fa0-39e2-4244-aa91-cdb1c27629cb/

or you can do it through sharepoint UI:

Change Web Part Properties in SharePoint 2010

> After you select and insert a Web Part into your page, you may want to
>   modify its properties to fit your needs. The number and type of
>   properties you can modify in SharePoint 2010 are based on what type of
>   Web Part you use.   When you select the Edit Web Part command by
>   clicking the Web Part menu (in the far right of the Web Part title),
>   SharePoint opens the Web Part tool pane. In some Web Parts, SharePoint
>   creates a link to this tool pane as part of the placeholder text.
>   Following is a list of properties in the tool pane common to List View
>   Web Parts:
>
> Appearance: The Appearance section allows you to title the Web Part,
>   fix the height and width as necessary, and determine the **chrome type**.
>   Chrome is another word for the Web Part surround; for example, title
>   and border options.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/change-web-part-properties-in-sharepoint-2010.html

shown through pictures :)

https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:ggVHboEicKIJ:https://www.madison.k12.al.us/departments/instruction/instructionaltechnology/websitewiki/Documents/Website%2520Help%2520Handouts/Setting%2520up%2520a%2520New%2520Web%2520Part%2520the%2520first%2520Time-ChromeType.pdf+&hl=en&gl=uk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESga34p4GQE_DJXG4_DH62IOsQlkgsPtazMLbznVYOF_4cWlC69KvpYBCENZOYYsoU-0QDp6YDvVcmScvh-62-x-XgUr-1crcYA9JkSOLlyzhX_eDE4fsQ7SegY6HHS-Vr23NjLM&sig=AHIEtbTh8On2RC7ZLRR6LCGxwiLZrEQcNA

You need to in sharepoint 2010:

1) goto your page that you want to edit.

2) on the ribbon select "page" tab.

3) select edit page within the ribbon (should be on the left hand side)

4) once selected the page will change to edit mode and you can now add webparts to the page. Find your webpart that you want to add the chrome... there should be a drop down arrow on the right handside of the webpart. Click it.. you should see some options. the one you want is "Edit Web Part". Select that option.

5) click "Appearance" in the new tab on the right hand side of the page

6) near the bottom you should see "chrome type". click on the dropdown and change to "Title and border". Now select apply and then ok.

You should now see the changes with your webpart wrapped in a border with title :)

or hover over the webpart and an arrow should appear on the top right side of the webpart, click it and select "Edit Web Part" and follow from 5 above!

hope this helps :)

Comment: I am on SharePoint 2010. By the way, the style in the picture i put in my post, is it OOTB or is it custom css?

Comment: Its OOTB, you just need to change the setting so that it looks like that!

Comment: i think i am missing something. exactly what setting makes chrome around editable field?

Comment: iv ammended my answer :)

Comment: actually what is on my page layout is NOT a webpart, it is a field(like <SharePointWebControls:TextField FieldName="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:TextField>). So there is no edit web part option.